# Would allowing preformatted anonymous critical comments help?

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes

It's sometimes frustrating to get downvotes on posts without getting any feedback on what's wrong with them.

Would people be more willing to provide critical comments if they could choose from a list of preformatted critical comments and post such a comment anonymously?

The comments would be preformatted so that they can't engage in anonymous personal attacks.

Comment: It'd certainly be interesting if people automatically got a second tier of options of "how this question/answer is bad" when they click the downvote button. "Inaccurate", "Misleading", "Unreadable", "Inapplicable" etc...

Comment: It doesn't matter if it would help, if you can't get SE to implement it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't think that's true. Exploration of the solution space is a good way to better understand the problem, even if some of the solutions end up being expensive or infeasible.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie There has been a lot of discussion on this and SE didn't implement anything. For example: [1) Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting) [2) Allow anonymous feedback on a downvote to be given through radio buttons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208030/allow-anonymous-feedback-on-a-downvote-to-be-given-through-radio-buttons) [3) Select from list of reasons when performing downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144851)

Comment: Maybe create an account with publically available password and have people use it to explain their downvotes? And name it Shy-chan or something.